# How to speed this up: Searching through multiple lists of dates to find closest match. [Python]

Tags: python, datetime, search, matching

I have one list of dates, `master_time`. For each date in `master_time`, I am searching for the closest match in four other lists of dates; `time1`,`time2`,`time3`, and `time4`. The results are appended to "closestmatch" lists which will later be used to join dataframes containing timeseries information from different data sources. (Perhaps there is a better approach to the initial problem, but this is what I have come up with so far)

To search through the 4 lists, I have created the following (rather bulky) loop:

```
master_time = [some list of dates...]
time1 = [some other list of dates...]
time2 = [some other list of dates...]
time3 = [some other list of dates...]
time4 = [some other list of dates...]

closest2=[];closest4=[];closest5=[];closest6=[]

for i in master_time:
    index_time=i
    closestTimestamp1=min(time1, key=lambda d: abs(d - index_time))
    closestTimestamp2=min(time2, key=lambda d: abs(d - index_time))
    closestTimestamp3=min(time3, key=lambda d: abs(d - index_time))
    closestTimestamp4=min(time4, key=lambda d: abs(d - index_time))
    closest1.append(str(closestTimestamp1))
    closest2.append(str(closestTimestamp2))
    closest3.append(str(closestTimestamp3))
    closest4.append(str(closestTimestamp4))
    print str(i)
```

This loop takes ~5 seconds per iteration (i.e. way too slow). I'm pretty new to Python in general, so I suspect there are a few ways I could streamline this to make it quicker. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Considering you're searching through each of the time lists multiple times, why don't you sort all the time lists then do a binary search? That would significantly reduce the time complexity of your algorithm.

Comment: @James Great advice - I haven't quite gotten it fully working yet but it already seems faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def find_best_match(master_list, secondary_list):
    master_list.sort()
    secondary_list.sort()

    secondary_len = len(secondary_list) - 1
    secondary_index = 0

    closests = []
    for master_value in master_list:
        while True:
            delta_current = abs(master_value - secondary_list[secondary_index])
            if secondary_index == secondary_len:
                break
            delta_next = abs(master_value - secondary_list[secondary_index+1])
            if delta_current < delta_next:
                break
            secondary_index += 1

        closests.append(secondary_list[secondary_index])

    return closests


master_list = [random.random() * 10000 for _ in range(1000000)]
list_1 = [random.random() * 10000 for _ in range(1000000)]
list_2 = [random.random() * 10000 for _ in range(1000000)]

closests_1 = find_best_match(master_list, list_1)
closests_2 = find_best_match(master_list, list_2)
```

This algorithm has a running complexity of N (and not N^2 like your algorithm or N*log(N) like James proposal) and take less than 2 seconds to match 2 lists of 1.000.000 randoms numbers